# Export to excel issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a asp.net page in which i am exporting gridview records to the excel files. But in some records only ############# is displayed in the excel file & when i view that record in function bar of the excel i am able to view correct record. So what can be the problem?

Waiting for your reply.Thanks a lot in advance.

Thanks
Mehul Thakkar

Comment: Even when i double click on that cell records are displayed instead of #######

Comment: What file format are you creating in your export?

Answer (score 2):

Make the columns wide enough so that the entire number can be displayed.

Comment: I have done that but still it's ######## is there any other way in which i can avoid such ### programatically while doing export to excel

Comment: Actually it's type is value so when we change it's type to general in excel it's shown properly. But is there any way we can accomplish this programmatically in c# side?

Answer (score 0):

####### in the cell only means that the cell is too narrow to fit the value (for some data types). If you make it wider the problem will disappear.